# Настройки приложения

Tags: java, android

Есть xml файл с разметкой 3 радиобаттона, при нажатии на каждый должны меняться фрагменты в контейнере, как можно сделать чтобы их положения сохранялись при закрытии приложения?

Comment: Самое очевидно в этом вопросе - использовать SharedPreference

Comment: @Chaynik примеры есть использования именно из фрагмента с похожей разметкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опустим, фрагменты, допустим, у вас `ViewFlipper` с тремя разметками, а `RadioButton`-ы их переключают. Тогда вам нужно при запуске активности получать текущее значение из `SharedPreferences`, если его не будет то использовать значение по умолчанию. Допустим, мы будем хранить индекс ребенка `ViewFlipper`-а с ключом `childIndex` (1-я разметка = 0, 2-я разметка = 1, 3-я разметка = 2) и по умолчанию открыта средняя разметка с индексом 1.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
int childIndex = prefs.getInt("childIndex", 1);
mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(childIndex);
```

А при переключении между `RadioButton`-ами помимо смены `View` нужно сохранять новое значение

```
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
    {
        View radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
        int index = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
        mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(index);
        prefs.edit().putInt("childIndex", index).commit();
    }
});
```

P. S. Донт форгот поменять `ViewFlipper` на фрагменты, я не смог написать пример на них, так как их еще не использовал.

P. P. S Заметьте, что всего вам нужно добавить 4 строки :) Узнать какое значение находится в `Preferences` можно перейдя по пути `data/data/<пекейж>/preferences/*.xml`

Comment: что такое этот вьюфлиппер и где его взять?

Comment: и куда эти строчки добавлять ?

Comment: Первый блок кода в `onCreate` сразу после `setContentView`. Второй блок кода это установка слушателя на `RadioGroup`. `ViewFlipper` есть в пакете `android.widget`я его в качестве примера показал, у вас же фрагменты

Comment: @Zdenek, что вам непонятно?

Comment: чем заменить ваш viewflipper из моего кода, фрагментом?

Comment: и ещё что за setDisplayedChild красным выделяет

Comment: Да, фрагментом. `setDisplayedChild` переключает показываемую `View`, я его в качестве примера привел.

Comment: а что мне использовать вместо setdisplayedchild

Comment: :( фрагменты переключайте